# Why can't I cancel a Flow using Job.cancel() when I start it for two times?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

In the App, I click "Start" button to display new information every 100ms, then click "Stop" button to stop display new information. it's work as my expection.

But If I click "Start" button for two times, then I click "Stop" button to hope to stop display new information, but the new information keep displaying, why? It seems that `myJob.cancel()` doesn't work.

```
class HandleMeter: ViewModel() {

  var myInfo = mutableStateOf("Hello")

  private lateinit var myJob: Job

    private fun soundDbFlow(period: Long = 100) = flow {
        while (true) {
            emit(soundDb())
            delay(period)
        }
    }

    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        myJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString() }
        }
    }

    fun cancelJob(){
        myJob.cancel()
    }
    
    ...
}


@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter) {

    var info = handleMeter.myInfo    
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(text = "Hello ${info.value}")

        Button(
            onClick = { handleMeter.calCurrentAsynNew() }
        ) {
            Text("Start")
        }

        Button(
              onClick = { handleMeter.cancelJob() }
        ) {
            Text("Stop")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `handleMeter.calCurrentAsynNew()` it starts a new coroutine and assigns the returned `Job` to `myJob`. When you click `Start` second time, it again starts a new coroutine and updates the value of `myJob` to this new `Job` instance but this doesn't cancel the previous coroutine, it's still running.

If you want to cancel previous coroutine when `calCurrentAsynNew()` is called, you will have to manually cancel it using `myJob.cancel()`

```kotlin
fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
    if(::myJob.isInitialized)
        myJob.cancel()
    myJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        soundDbFlow().collect { myInfo.value = it.toString() + " OK Asyn  " + a++.toString() }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `lateinit var myJob: Job` you could have also used `var myJob: Job? = null` and then to cancel it, use `myJob?.cancel()`

`Dispatchers.IO` is also not required in this case.

Comment: I would say using lateinit in this way is a roundabout and verbose way to make Kotlin behave like Java, where it’s easy to get an exception by failing to check a variable’s state every time you use it. It shouldn’t be used like this. The OP’s code will crash if the public functions of this ViewModel are called in a certain order.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is great! And more, why is `Dispatchers.IO`  also not required in this case? You know that `viewModelScope.launch{...} ` run in main thread and `soundDbFlow()` keep running which maybe cause main thread freeze such as the parameter of `delay(period)` in fun `soundDbFlow(0)`  is assigned to 0 .

Comment: @Tenfour04 I didn't fully understand what you meant here. Are you suggesting some improvement in my answer? And yeah it's correct that if `clearJob` is called before `calCurrentAsynNew`, the app will crash. Probably it's better to use the nullable `Job` here.

Comment: @HelloCW Yeah like if you set the delay time to be 0, then probably thread will freeze and switching to background thread would be a better choice. Although I can't think of any practical use case for period of 0 seconds. In normal cases where flow emits values in intervals, you can collect it on main thread as `collect` will only suspend that particular coroutine and not block the entire thread.

Comment: I was suggesting more strongly condemning the use of `lateinit` in this situation, is all. No problem with your answer.